# Django javascript translation giving error on page load

Tags: javascript, html, django

This is what my urls.py looks like:

```
js_info_dict = {
    'domain': 'djangojs',
    'packages': ('project',),
}

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('project.urls')),
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html', 'authentication_form': LoginForm}, name = 'login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'next_page': '/login'}),
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('', (r'^jsi18n/$', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog', js_info_dict), )
```

This is what I have in my html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog' %}"></script>
```

I have run `django-admin makemessages -d djangojs -l fr` and made my changes to the `djangojs.po` file. I then ran `django-admin compilemessages`. I see the the `djangojs.mo` file. When I go to my site, it is giving me an AttributeError that points to the line of HTML code above. How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else having this problem, this is what I did to solve the issue in addition to running `django-admin makemessages -d djangojs -l fr` and `django-admin compilemessages`.

urls.py should look like:

```
from django.views.i18n import JavaScriptCatalog
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('project.urls')),
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html', 'authentication_form': LoginForm}, name = 'login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'next_page': '/login'}),
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    url(r'^jsi18n/$', JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(), name='javascript-catalog'),
]
```

This should be in template:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'javascript-catalog' %}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
js_info_dict = {
    'domain': 'djangojs',
    'packages': ('project',),
}
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^jsi18n/$', js_info_dict, name='javascript-catalog'),
)
```

> In template

```
`<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'javascript-catalog' %}">`</script>
```

Comment: This gives me a TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().