# Django App TypeError django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, digital-ocean, django-i18n

I have an django app and this app running in my local server. But it can not run my digitalocean server.
When enter this app,  give this error *Internal Server Error*.
I am using git service and I tested lots of time same codes in my local server. Also I tried to run manage.py runserver in digitalocean and give this error.

app_name : writed here my app name

**urls.py**

```
js_info_dict = {
   'domain': 'djangojs',
   'packages': ('app_name',),
}


urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    ...
    url(r'^jsi18n/$', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog', js_info_dict),
]
```

**command ./manage.py runserver** error
  also **gunicorn.log** show same error

> Unhandled exception in thread started by 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
>       fn(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
>       self.check(display_num_errors=True)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 374, in check
>       include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in _run_checks
>       return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
>       new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
>       return check_resolver(resolver)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
>       for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in **get**
>       res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 313, in url_patterns
>       patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in **get**
>       res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 306, in urlconf_module
>       return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 37, in import_module
>       **import**(name)
>     File "/home/django/retailflux/retailflux/urls.py", line 34, in 
>       url(r'^jsi18n/$', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog', js_info_dict),
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/urls/**init**.py", line 85, in url
>       raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().')
>   TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django >= 1.10 no longer allows to specify views as a string (e.g. `'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog'`) in URL patterns.

Comment: my django-admin version is 1.10.1 and still running my local server but just doesnt run server

Comment: Yes, that means you can not specify views as strings.

Comment: I understand you are right. I saw this an error in internet. But ı dont understand. How this app running local but doesnt server.

Comment: Also I tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701434/django-javascript-translation-giving-error-on-page-load it is  running server but in my local server this is not running. django versions are the same in server and local computer

Comment: Did you try: from django.views.i18n import JavaScriptCatalog url(r'^jsi18n/$', JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(), name='javascript-catalog')

Comment: Yes I tried and running. But I dont understand. Everything are the same but there is an error on server. I want to cry. How it can be.  Thanks for answer